# Ansible: Loop on included files

Tags: ansible

I wrote a playbook/roles to create list of vhost on a webserver.

I have a big dict describing all the sites. It's not easily maintainable and I would like to define each vhost in a separate vars file and loop on these files.
But I don't really know how to do this.

Here is my actual code:

```
    - name: "Create domain configuration"
  include_role:
    name: webserver/domain
  loop: "{{ list_domains | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: domain
```

With the dict definition :

```
list_domains:
  domain1:
    server_name: "domain1.com"
    server_alias:
      - "domain1.fr"
    certificate:
      method: "webroot"
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "128M"
  database:
    type: "mysql"
  cms:
    type: "prestashop"
  domain2:
    server_name: domain2.com
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "512M"
```

The goal is to have a directory with *domain1.yml* and *domain2.yml* with the domains definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `host_vars` directory creating a file with the name of each of your hosts.

Example:

Directory

```
 host_vars/
   - domain1.com
   - domain2.comq
 your_playbook.yml
 roles/
   - role1/
    ......
```

`domain1.com` file:

```
    server_name: "domain1.com"
    server_alias:
      - "domain1.fr"
    certificate:
      method: "webroot"
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "128M"
    database:
      type: "mysql"
    cms:
      type: "prestashop"
```

`domain2.com` file:

```
    server_name: domain2.com
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "512M"
```

Each host has its own variables, then modify your playbook as below

```yaml
- hosts: domain1.com, domain2.com
  tasks:

  - name: "Create domain configuration"
    include_role:
      name: webserver/domain
```

Comment: It's an interresting method, I would have to edit the inventory and playbook when adding a new site/domain

Comment: Actually I don't understand how to make it works. I have many host server, each of them hosting many domains. How is it possible to deploy all domain on a single host? @gary-lopez

Comment: any advice for complete implementation @gary ?

Comment: I found how to play with the inventory for my goal, thks.